# Django new field "JSONField" error - Column does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, jsonfield

I created a dummy project just to test the new field **JSONField** of Django but the column doesn't not appear to be created (I am using Postgresql).

```
class Author(models.Model):

   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   description = models.TextField()
   slug = models.SlugField()
   details = models.JSONField()

   class Meta:
     verbose_name = "Author"

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

If i go to the database, the column is not created -- [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Edmke.png)

When i go to the admin view page of the table Author i get the following error -- [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0g9w.png)

The error in the admin panel is understandable: you cannot view a column that does not exist. Do you guys have the same error? I can't find this error with JSONField anywhere.

Thanks

***Note: This is my first post.***

**EDIT** I create all the fields in the same time. Migration file:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.3 on 2020-11-20 10:35

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Author',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('description', models.TextField()),
                ('slug', models.SlugField()),
                ('details', models.JSONField()),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'Author',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Migrated with sucess:

```
Migrations for 'blog':
  blog/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Author
```

Comment: Have you migrated your changes via `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Question edited

Comment: if you already migrated. Then I guess migration probably frick up somewhere, try removing the field, migrate, and then add the field back. or maybe you have multiple databases(?)

Comment: If i remove the field, a migration is created with the instruction to remove it. But that doesn't work because the migration fails:  "column "details" of relation "blog_author" does not exist"

Answer (score 0):

check that you migration was applied to the right database

Comment: Hi, i forgot to mention that i create all the fields at the same time. I edit the question

Comment: I added a new field and the same table that i showed is updated. Seems that the field JSONField is the problem here

Comment: If you run manage dbshell, you could look to see the table description either with .schema (sqlite) or \d tablename with posgres